# Ordering references with `references.tex` file

Tags: bibliographies

I import my references in my main document via:

```
\label{References}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\input{references}

\nocite{*}
```

and have a `references.tex` file in which my references are:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{S3group}

P. J. Cameron, Permutation Groups, Cambridge University Press (1999).

\end{thebibliography}
```

How do I order the references in order of appearance? Does this only work with files such as `Bibliography.bib` or is it possible here as well?

Comment: The instructions `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` and `\nocite{*}` have no effect unless you use BibTeX to generate the (formatted) bibliography. Since it looks like you're building the bibliography entirely "by hand", nothing is achieved by running these macros. Incidentally, the order of appearance of the bib entries in the pdf file is the same as the ordering you've applied by hand to the `\bibitem` items in the `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my question: Is there a way to apply the instructions such as `\nocite{*}` or the ordering to files such as `reference.tex` as well?

Comment: No, if you manually enter the entries you also have to sort them manually. \nocite{*} is unnessary as all entries are shown anyway.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you manually enter the entries you also have to sort them manually. `\nocite{*}` is unnessary as all entries are shown anyway.

Comment: Another on off the list.